# Замена тега с сохранением содержимого

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как на странице заменить все заголовки `h2-h6` на тег `div` с сохранением всех атрибутов и у которых есть класс `title`?

```
$('h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').each(function(i,el){
    var $h = $(el);
    console.log($h);
    if($h.hasClass('title')){
        $($h).replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){
            return $("<div />").html(oldHTML);
        });
    }
})
```

такой код не сохраняет атрибуты

**P.S.**
такое решение правильное?

```
$('h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').each(function(i,el){
    var $h = $(el);
    if($h.hasClass('title')){
        var div = document.createElement('div'),
            $div = $(div);
        $.each($h[0].attributes, function(i,attr){
            var a = attr.nodeName||attr.name;
            var val = attr.nodeValue;
            $div.attr(a, val);
        });
        $div.html($h.html());
        $h.replaceWith($div);
    }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3665820/6275986

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith(function(){
    var $div = $('<div/>', { html: $(this).html() });

    $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute) {
      $div.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    });

    return $div;
  });
});
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { background-color: red; }
div { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>H1</h1>
<h2>H2</h2>
<h3>H3</h3>
<h4>H4</h4>
<h5>H5</h5>
<h6>H6</h6>
```